# No consigo dar los estilos que necesito al menú principal (wordpress)

Tags: html5, css3, wordpress, menú

Buenos días.

No encuentro la forma de a las opciones del menú cambiarles el color cuando esta seleccionada una sección de la web. por defecto la plantilla me pone la opción con bold, pero a parte quiero darle otro color.

El menú en versión smartphone cuando se pulsa en el y se expanden las opciones, se quedan alineadas a la derecha, con poco tamaño. quiero ponerle un witdh:100% y el texto de los enlaces con más tamaño.

El theme es comprado en elegantthemes.com se llama Vertex.

Aquí podeis ver el menú: www.jamondemono.com/prueba

```
<header id="main-header">
    <header id="main-header">
        <div id="logo">
                        <img class="imglogo" width="100px" height="100px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo3.png">

                    </div>
        <div id="top-menu">
            <div class="container clearfix">




                <nav>
                <?php
                    $menuClass = 'nav';
                    if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'vertex_disable_toptier' ) ) $menuClass .= ' et_disable_top_tier';
                    $primaryNav = '';

                    $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'echo' => false ) );

                    if ( '' == $primaryNav ) :
                ?>
                    <ul class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuClass ); ?>">
                        <?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'vertex_home_link' ) ) { ?>
                            <li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home','Vertex' ); ?></a></li>
                        <?php }; ?>

                        <?php show_page_menu( $menuClass, false, false ); ?>
                        <?php show_categories_menu( $menuClass, false ); ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php
                    else :
                        echo( $primaryNav );
                    endif;
                ?>
                </nav>

                <?php do_action( 'et_header_top' ); ?>
            </div> <!-- .container -->
        </div> <!-- #top-menu -->


    </header> <!-- #main-header --> <div id="logo">
                        <img class="imglogo" width="100px" height="100px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo3.png">

                    </div>
        <div id="top-menu">
            <div class="container clearfix">


                <!-- <div id="et-logo">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo3.png">

                </div> -->

                <nav>
                <?php
                    $menuClass = 'nav';
                    if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'vertex_disable_toptier' ) ) $menuClass .= ' et_disable_top_tier';
                    $primaryNav = '';

                    $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'echo' => false ) );

                    if ( '' == $primaryNav ) :
                ?>
                    <ul class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuClass ); ?>">
                        <?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'vertex_home_link' ) ) { ?>
                            <li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home','Vertex' ); ?></a></li>
                        <?php }; ?>

                        <?php show_page_menu( $menuClass, false, false ); ?>
                        <?php show_categories_menu( $menuClass, false ); ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php
                    else :
                        echo( $primaryNav );
                    endif;
                ?>
                </nav>

                <?php do_action( 'et_header_top' ); ?>
            </div> <!-- .container -->
        </div> <!-- #top-menu -->


    </header> <!-- #main-header --> 


/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------[DEFAULT DROPDOWN SETTINGS]---*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

.nav li ul { position:absolute; top:-999em; }
.nav li ul, .et_mobile_menu { z-index: 9999; width: 238px; background: #25383b; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); padding: 10px 0 25px; display: none; text-align: left; }
    .nav li { position: relative; }
        .nav ul li { float: none; }
            .nav ul a { display:block !important; float: none !important; }
.nav li:hover ul, ul.nav li.sfHover ul { left: -19px; top: 48px; }
    .nav li:hover li ul, .nav li.sfHover li ul, .nav li:hover ul, .nav li li:hover ul { top:-999em; }

.nav li li { padding: 0; height: auto !important; display: block !important; }
.nav li li ul { z-index: 1000; }
    .nav li li a:link, .nav li li a:visited, .et_mobile_menu a { display: block !important; height: auto; padding: 9px 10px 9px 30px !important; }
    .nav li:hover { visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */ }

.nav li li:hover ul, ul.nav li li.sfHover ul { left: 238px; top: -10px; }

.nav.sf-arrows li.menu-item-has-children > a:after { content: " \00bb"; }




#top-menu { /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); */border-bottom: 1px solid #959494;position: relative; background: #25383b;height: 77px; }
    .container { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; position: relative; }
    #top-menu .container { padding: 32px 0 0; }
    #main-header .container, #pre-footer .container { text-align: center; }
        #top-menu li { display: inline-block; }
            #top-menu a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 12px; display: block; }
            #top-menu nav a:hover, .description h2 a:hover { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); }
            #top-menu li.current-menu-item > a { font-weight: 800;}
            #top-menu ul.nav > li > a { padding-bottom: 32px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Con CSS puedes hacerlo aplicando el siguiente selector:

```
header ul li.current-menu-item {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No funciona. ya tengo esto: #top-menu li.current-menu-item > a { font-weight: 800;} le pongo color: #000; y tampoco hace nada

Comment: @Rafahernandez pues debería funcionar, ¿no será problema de caché? con wordpress suele ocurrir que no actualiza los cambios. O quiza necesitas ponerle un `!important` porque hay otros estilos sobreescribiendolo

Comment: @Rafahernandez tienes esto en la etiqueta `style` en el html `#top-menu a, .et_mobile_menu a { color: #ffffff; }`. O lo cambias ahí mismo o usas `!important`